# sql server - how to execute the second half of 'or' clause only when first one fails

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose I have a table with following records

```
value                    text
company/about            about Us
company                  company
company/contactus        company contact
```

I have a very simple query in sql server as below. I am having problem with the 'or' condition. In below query, I am trying to find text for value 'company/about'. If it is not found, then only I want to run the other side of 'or'. The below query returns two records as below

```
value                       text
company/about               about Us
company                     company
```

Query

```
 select 
        *
    from 
        tbl
    where 
        value='company/about' or
         value=substring('company/about',0,charindex('/','company/about'))
```

How can I modify the query so the result set looks like

```
value                       text
company/about               about Us
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit roundabout, but you can check for the existence of results from the first where clause:

```
select 
    *
from 
    tbl
where 
    value='company/about' or
(
    not exists (select * from tbl where value='company/about')
    and
    value=substring('company/about',0,charindex('/','company/about'))
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your second condition can be re-written as `value = 'company'` this would work (at least for the data and query you've presented):

```
select top(1) [value], [text]
from dbo.MyTable
where value in ('company/about', 'company')
order by len(value) desc
```

The `TOP()` ignores the second row if both are found, and the `ORDER BY` ensures that the first row is always the one with 'company/about', if it exists.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This works too. I am not able to Vote up yet